# NHibernate query to get record matching the max of a column

Tags: c#, asp.net, nhibernate

I want to do the equivalent of the following SQL in nHibernate -

```
SELECT * FROM healthcheckreports 
WHERE timestamp = (SELECT max(timestamp) 
  FROM healthcheckreports;
```

I am able to get the `max(timestamp)` using the following:

```
var criteria = session.CreateCriteria<HealthCheckReport>();
criteria.SetProjection(Projections.Max("TimeStamp"));
criteria.UniqueResult();
```

But what I want is the record whose timestamp matches the `max(timestamp)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about this:

```
// the inner (sub) select resulting in just max TimeStamp
var maxTimestamp = DetachedCriteria.For<HealthCheckReport>()
    .SetProjection(Projections.Max("TimeStamp"));

// the root query with a WHERE
var criteria = session.CreateCriteria<HealthCheckReport>()
    .Add(Subqueries.PropertyEq("TimeStamp", maxTimestamp));

// the most fresh one
var result = criteria
    .UniqueResult();
```